# Next.js user get location

Tags: next.js, location, cloudflare

I want to bring the user location with cloudflare. Localhost and google cloud bring different results. I want to access the location information of the member, not the server. What can I use instead of getStaticProps?

My Code;

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const one = await fetch("https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace");
  const two = await one.text();
  var data = two.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '","').replace(/\=+/g, '":"');
  data = '{"' + data.slice(0, data.lastIndexOf('","')) + '"}';
  var locale = JSON.parse(data);

  return {
    props: { locale },
  };
}

function myPage(props) {
   return (props.locale.loc)
}
```

solved code;

```
  let [locData, setLocData] = useState("EN");
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace")
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((two) => {
        var data = two.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '","').replace(/\=+/g, '":"');
        data = '{"' + data.slice(0, data.lastIndexOf('","')) + '"}';
        var locale = JSON.parse(data);
        setLocData(locale.loc);
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: If you're doing this for i18n then don't. There are much [better](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next) [ways](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing). If you want a user's location better [ask them for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API). Anyway, you need to fetch the data from client side if you want a user's location like that. Use a `useEffect` hook.

Comment: thanks, i won't use it for i18n. useEffect solved my problem.